# perl : how to print after a specific line

Tags: perl

For example, `my.txt` containts

```
a
b
xx
c
d
```

I want print from the second line below lines that contains xx

I tried

```
perl -nle 'if(/xx/){$n=$.};print if $.>($n+1)' my.txt
```

But it didn't work. It just print all lines.

Comment: `perl -ne 'print if (/xx/ .. 0)>1' my.txt` => http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Comment: Try this: `perl -ne 'if(/xx/){$n=1;next};print if $n' my.txt`

Comment: Hi, @Сухой27 Thank you so much. I read the doc. But I still don't understand why `.. ` expression can be compared to a number? Because the doc says `..` is boolean

Comment: Yes, you can use it like boolean, but actually it is a sequence of numbers. (`The value returned is either the empty string for false, or a sequence number (beginning with 1) for true.`)

Comment: @Сухой27 Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Before $n is defined it is interpreted as 0 (zero), meaning that $. > 1 will also be printed before xx. This might be what you wanted:

```
perl -nle 'if(/xx/){$n=$.}; print if defined($n) and $. > $n+1' my.txt
```